# How do I move an object using a timer and the key press event (Like snake)

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to move a button automatically using a timer and want it to change direction when another key is pressed, kinda like what happens in snake

I have used a string to set what the direction should be, but this doesn't work.

string x = "right";

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        timer1.Interval = 1000;
        timer1.Start();

    }

    private void Player_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.W)
        {
            string x = "up";
        }
        else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.S)
        {
            string x = "down";
        }
        else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.D)
        {
            string x = "right";
        }
        else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.A)
        {
            string x = "left";
        }

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        while (x == "up")
        {
            Player.Top -= 10;
        }
        while (x == "down")
        {
            Player.Top += 10;
        }
        while (x == "right")
        {
            Player.Left += 10;
        }
        while (x == "left")
        {
            Player.Left -= 10;
        }
    }
}
```

The button just disappears, but I want it to move by ten until it gets a key press like "D" then it changes direction

Comment: Try to use the Location property. `Player.Loaction = new Point(x, y)`

Comment: Do you mean like this? while (x == "up")
            {
                Player.Location = new Point(Y += 10);
            }

Comment: Do not use while() in the Tick event handler, that's going to be a very short game.  Use if().  And add the "game over" checks.

Comment: If you set X="right" as default timer will move it right before the player is in act. So put a condition return if x is null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1: You are creating variable 'x' every time means locally in player_keyDown event so create it globally.

2: you are using while loop it, not needed as you are already using timer_tick.

3: Instead of Top, Left use Location property of button it gives you X, Y co-ordinate

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        timer1.Interval = 1000;
        timer1.Start();
    }

    string x = "right";
    private void Player_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.W)
        {
            x = "up";
        }
        else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.S)
        {
            x = "down";
        }
        else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.D)
        {
            x = "right";
        }
        else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.A)
        {
            x = "left";
        }
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (x == "up")
        {
            Player.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(Player.Location.X, Player.Location.Y - 10);
        }
        if (x == "down")
        {
            Player.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(Player.Location.X, Player.Location.Y + 10);
        }
        if (x == "right")
        {
            Player.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(Player.Location.X + 10, Player.Location.Y);
        }
        if (x == "left")
        {
            Player.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(Player.Location.X - 10, Player.Location.Y);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Okay perfect thanks, do you know how I'd be able to make it so if it moves in one direction, say right, it can't go the opposite, in this case left?

Comment: if it goes to right direction then don't change its value to left  means you restrict the user to change value to left .only add condition in if block  if (e.KeyCode == Keys.A && x!="right")
        {
            x = "left";
        }